# Java regex to remove multiple occurrences of a pattern from a sentence

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to pass a sentence to a function and have multiple occurrences of a pattern removed before returning.

My function looks like this....

```
  public String removeExtraStars(String str){
    String b = str.replaceAll("\\*\\s{2,}", "* ");
    return b;
  }
```

An example input is `"hi my name is * *"`
I am trying to get the output to look like `"hi my name is *"`
But it just wont do it.
I have tried it on string like `"my dinner was * * nice"`
hoping it would output `"my dinner was * nice"`
But nothing worked.
Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong.
thanks

p.s. I think the most complicated output would look like this `"* and * and * and *"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to change your regex to search for not only a `*` but for whitespace and additional `*`'s afterwards.

```
String str = "hi my name is * * * and * is * *";
String b = str.replaceAll("\\*(\\s+\\*)+", "*");
```

output:

```
hi my name is *  and * is *
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression replaces `*` (asterisk followed by two spaces) but not `* *`.  If I read your request correctly, you need to group before the quantifier: `(\\*\\s){2,}` which says "astrisk followed by space, at least two times".